# Proving relation between x and 1/x

Tags: real-analysis

How will you prove this Lemma (using axioms of ordering)?
**Lemma:** if $x\in P$ (positive numbers), then $\frac{1}{x}\in P$.

After messing around with this for a little bit I managed to prove that $x+\frac{1}{x}\geq 2$ and proving the lemma from there. However, this seems to me like a very long prove and that there's a more straightforward way of doing it.

My current strategy is assume by contradiction that $\frac{1}{x}\notin P$ which contradicts $(\frac{1}{x})^2\in P$.

Comment: Your strategy works as long as you can assume that $1\gt 0$ because $0\ge\frac{1}{x}$ and $x\gt 0$ implies $x\cdot 0\ge x(\frac{1}{x})\to 0\ge 1$.

Comment: What do you mean by "axioms of ordering"? What you are trying to prove involves arithmetic operations as well as just an ordering, so you surely need to appeal to the axioms of an ordered ring or field.

Answer (score 6):

$x\cdot \dfrac{1}{x}=1$, which is positive.

Therefore $x$ and $\dfrac{1}{x}$ have the same sign.

Comment: How does this use the order axioms?

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative

$$\frac{x}{\dfrac{1}{x}}=x^2>0$$

therefore $x$ and $\dfrac{1}{x}$ have the same sign.